# how to combine a line and a path in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image: strand]

I have a path with a black fill that has two curves that meet at a point. I also have a vertical line that connects the beaks of both curves. How can I combine them so the right white triangle disappears and is replaced with black?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Expand the line into a shape: `Object > Expand...`
2. Select both shapes (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + click with the black arrow tool)
3. Choose the first option 'Unite' in the Pathfinder palette (`Window > Pathfinder`)

In case your curved shape had a stroke, that stroke will disappear when you unite. In this case, you need to expand the original shape, yielding its stroke and its fill as separate shapes. Unite those, and unite the expanded stroke with the resulting shape.

Comment: It didn't work. This is what I get: http://imgur.com/AsyBGN3

Comment: ah, your original curved shape also had a stroke, that was hard to see. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that almost worked. I still had a triangle in the middle: http://imgur.com/0GVRmmL but I was able to shift select the 3 points and delete it. Is there any way to do that automatically?

Comment: oh, I thought you wanted to preserve the hole. You could resize the rectangle that is your expanded stroke so it covers the hole before uniting the last time. But your solution is about as easy.